# How to compile only changed file using gradle build in java projects

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, javac

I am using gradle to build a java project.

I see that whenever there is a change in one java file entire projects gets rebuilt. Is there a way to compile only affected java files instead of all the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle now supports *compile avoidance*, and has support for incremental compilation since earlier. You do not have to do anything to enjoy these features. Just update Gradle. See https://blog.gradle.org/incremental-compiler-avoidance