# Gitlab Runner configuration to ignore folder builded on server

Tags: gradle, gitlab-ci

I'm new with Gitlab CI. Every time Gitlab CI run, it replace old folder on server. I have small problem when I want to reduce time Gradle build for project which include DL4J (very big size and take time to build). So I want it keep build folder from last version. [I follow this to reduce time build by gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042305/how-to-compile-only-changed-file-using-gradle-build-in-java-projects). 
Question: Is that possible to skip some folder by config of gitlab ci to keep it exist. This is my gitlab ci

```
stages:
  - build

something_run:
  stage: build
  script:
    - gradle build
    - systemctl restart myproject
  tags:
    - ml
  only:
    - master
```

When it run, gradle will build project and time to build quite long. So I want next time CI run it will not delete last build version.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AlekseyTsalolikhin I added question but not sure how to explain my problem

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `cache` (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cache)

`cache` is used to specify a list of files and directories which should be cached between jobs.

GitLab CI/CD provides a caching mechanism that can be used to save time when your jobs are running.

See also https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/index.html